# how to add loading text in a .load function?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this jquery function to load a page based on a `href` link:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#test a").click(function( e ){
            e.preventDefault();
            var href = $( this ).attr('href');
            $("#content").load( href , function(){
            $('#content').hide().fadeIn(500);
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

My question is, how to show loading div while the href page is loading?

```
<div id=loading>LOADING...</div>
```

thank you friends!

Answer (score 1):

You may do like this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#test a").click(function( e ){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#loading").html("Loading");
        var href = $( this ).attr('href');
        $("#content").load( href , function(){
        $('#content').hide().fadeIn(500);
        });
       $("#loading").html("");
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do the `loading`div hidden by default:

```
#loading{
    display: none;
}
```

Then, show it BEFORE you call `load` and hide it in the callback function.

```
....
var href = $( this ).attr('href');
$("#loading").show();
$("#content").load( href , function(){
        $("#loading").hide();
....
```